# HTTP Dynamic Streaming - Manually Select Stream

Tags: iphone, ios, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

Are there any javascript methods, etc that would let me manually select the stream that is being used during playback of a dynamic stream playlist in iOS.

By default, it's based off the current bandwidth, but I have some use cases that I would like to be able to on the fly change the playlist that is being used to stream the video.

I would like to be able to change the stream during video playback, so just pointing to another m3u8 playlist isn't really an option for what I'm trying to do.

Ideas - or not possible?